# Best way to create a 2D scrolling map

Tags: visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I am writing a program in visual basic 2010 to create a 2D scrolling map.  I am using Pictureboxes at the moment, all 50 by 70 in size.  It starts with 1, and depending on what is needed may easily end up with 1000 - 2000 of them.  They all need to be clickable.  I am concerned it might use too many resources and run too slow.  Can anyone tell me what the best approach to make something like would be.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common method is to only draw the tiles (or pictureboxes in your case) when they can be seen by the player's camera. So you should first determine how many boxes fill the screen and then calculate whether or not they are within the bounds of the player camera as represented by a rectangle. Additionally, you should draw boxes slightly outside the player's view (1 or 2 additional boxes per edge, this is explained below).

When the player moves, move the position of the world, not the player. So if the player moves left, scroll all of the tiles to the right while the player sprite remains stationary. Now when a player's position changes you should check again which tiles are visible in the player's screen. Since you are drawing additional rows slightly outside the view of the player, the edges will smoothly scroll in and will not 'pop' in as is a common problem when starting out.

Since you are only drawing tiles which are visible to the player, your game should run a lot more efficiently. It is OK to store this data in a 2D array in memory for now. In the future when you have huge maps, it may be a good idea to load sections of your map which are far outside of the player's view from disk to memory. You don't want to load in map data from disk which the player can navigate to before it is fully loaded.

Exactly how much map data to store in memory is up to you and depends on what platforms you want to release on and other constraints.

Additionally, you may want to look into different rendering libraries. Common low-level libraries are DirectX and OpenGL. These libraries work directly with your graphics card to dramatically speed up rendering. There are libraries built on top of those for various languages, but I don't know any for Visual Basic. An example for JavaScript is PixiJS. Additionally, there are full featured game creation libraries such as Unity or the Unreal Engine 3.